# How to design complex UI in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, material-design, smooth-scrolling

How can I have a ViewPager above a RecyclerView, or have several RecyclerViews in a ScrollView? I designed the following layout, but it has some problems when scrolling.
What is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dcdcdc"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
           />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**I have tried `compile 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'` with**

```
 <com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader2.RecyclerViewHeader
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
```

**1- firstly it supports 11 sdk or greater,

2- secondly `ViewPager` wont work in header `RecyclerView`. 
and i have tried `RecyclerView` `layout_width="wrap_content"` but it is just supported in sdk21 .**

**How can I solve the RecyclerView scrolling ?**

Comment: Any help would be appreciate greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try losing the top ScrollView and using a ListView instead of RecyclerView.

ScrollView is unnecessary here and you need a hack for ViewPager to work with RecyclerView as it consumes all touch events. It would be simpler if you could get away with a ListView.

Comment: Thanks , there is no different between listview and RecyclerView  why should i use listView ? . and with scrollview i want to scroll viewPager up and hide it gradually

Comment: Because with ListView you won't have a problem with a ViewPager. I'm not sure what you mean by scrolling and hiding it gradually, but if it's like an animation for sliding out when you press a button then you use resize animation for that, not ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your view pager to app bar in collapssing toolbar layout and it will be ok